# .NET objects in Labview

Tags: .net, web-services, labview

i want to consume a .NET web service which returns an object of some class in labview. How do i convert the returning object into a labview object. Currently it just returns a srting. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you used the Import Web Services feature of LabVIEW? This is located in Tools -> Import menu. It should take care of converting the data type for you; unless the data is complex or encoded some how. For help using the import function, see this page: http://zone.ni.com/devzone/cda/tut/p/id/4728#toc4

This should create an lvlib containing VIs that will return the data in a LabVIEW format.

Try importing the WSDL below and then create a VI that connects the open vi to the checkcc vi to the close vi. The output of the CheckCC vi is created by the import function, and is a cluster consisting of a string and a Boolean.

https://secure.cdyne.com/creditcardverify/luhnchecker.asmx?wsdl